# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \cdot \frac{2^{2^n}+5}{2^{2^n+1}+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Check convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \cdot \frac{2^{2^n}+5}{2^{2^n+1}+1}$$
I suppose its not absolute convergent, but whats more?

Answer (score 3):

The series is **divergent** since
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{2^n}+5}{2^{2^n+1}+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1+\dfrac5{2^{2^n}}}{2+\dfrac1{2^{2^n}}}=\frac12 \neq 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The convergence of $\sum a_n$ requires $a_n\to 0$. It is immediate to see that $a_n\not\to 0 $.